Troubleshooting C Macro Expansion Compilation Errors about format specifiers
Recently, I was working to get and set some fields on a UCI file. To get the failure reason appropriately, I decided to use some macro as given below:
#define HANDLE_UCI_ERR(_cond_, _fmt_, ...)                  \
    do {                                                    \
        if (_cond_) {                                       \
            char *err_msg = NULL;                           \
            uci_get_errorstr(g_uci_ctx, &err_msg, _fmt_);   \
            ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);                    \
            free(err_msg);                                  \
            goto bail;                                      \
        }                                                   \
    } while (0)

Note, this is not relevant with the question, but to compile uci code I installed its library using the steps given here.
However, it gives me following compile error:
gcc trial.c -luci -o trial
trial.c: In function ‘main’:
trial.c:37:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘err_msg’
   37 |    MY_ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
      |           ^~~~~~~
trial.c:14:38: note: in definition of macro ‘MY_PRINT’
   14 |   printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
      |                                      ^~~
trial.c:37:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_ERR’
   37 |    MY_ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
      |    ^~~~~~
trial.c:72:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘HANDLE_UCI_ERR’
   72 |  HANDLE_UCI_ERR(rc != UCI_OK, "Not able to load package %s", PACKAGE_STR);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
trial.c:14:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
   14 |   printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
      |          ^~~~~~~
trial.c:19:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_PRINT’
   19 |   MY_PRINT("Error  : ", fmt, ##arg)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
trial.c:37:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_ERR’
   37 |    MY_ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
      |    ^~~~~~
trial.c:72:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘HANDLE_UCI_ERR’
   72 |  HANDLE_UCI_ERR(rc != UCI_OK, "Not able to load package %s", PACKAGE_STR);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
trial.c:14:29: note: format string is defined here
   14 |   printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
      |                            ~^
      |                             |
      |                             char *
trial.c:14:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
   14 |   printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
      |          ^~~~~~~
trial.c:19:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_PRINT’
   19 |   MY_PRINT("Error  : ", fmt, ##arg)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
trial.c:37:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_ERR’
   37 |    MY_ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
      |    ^~~~~~
trial.c:72:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘HANDLE_UCI_ERR’
   72 |  HANDLE_UCI_ERR(rc != UCI_OK, "Not able to load package %s", PACKAGE_STR);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
trial.c:14:32: note: format string is defined here
   14 |   printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
      |                               ~^
      |                                |
      |                                int

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1

To be honest, I am not sure what is the problem in the code. Therefore, I wanted to share reproducible version of it. Here is the simplified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uci.h>

#define DEBUG_ERROR_LEVEL 2


int loglevel = 7;


#define MY_PRINT(prefix, fmt, arg...) do {              \
        printf("[DM] " prefix " [%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##arg); \
    } while (0)

#define MY_ERR(fmt, arg...)         \
    if (loglevel > DEBUG_ERROR_LEVEL)   \
        MY_PRINT("Error  : " fmt, ##arg)

#define HANDLE_UCI_ERR(_cond_, _fmt_, ...)                              \
    do {                                                            \
        if (_cond_) {                                           \
            char *err_msg = NULL;                           \
            uci_get_errorstr(g_uci_ctx, &err_msg, _fmt_);   \
            MY_ERR(err_msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);         \
            free(err_msg);                                  \
            goto bail;                                      \
        }                                                       \
    } while (0)

static const char *PACKAGE_STR = "package";

static struct uci_context *g_uci_ctx;



__attribute__((constructor))
void init_uci_context() {
    g_uci_ctx = uci_alloc_context();
    if (!g_uci_ctx) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (uci_set_confdir(g_uci_ctx, "/home/aziz.kavas@corp.airties.com/tmp/config/") != 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

__attribute__((destructor))
void cleanup_uci_context() {
    if (g_uci_ctx) {
        uci_free_context(g_uci_ctx);
    }
}

int main() {
    int rc = 0;
    struct uci_package *pkg = NULL;

    rc = uci_load(g_uci_ctx, PACKAGE_STR, &pkg);
    HANDLE_UCI_ERR(rc != UCI_OK, "Not able to load package %s", PACKAGE_STR);

bail:
    uci_unload(g_uci_ctx, pkg);
    return rc;
}



To solve it, I can either update HANDLE_UCI_ERR macro as below:
#define HANDLE_UCI_ERR(cond, fmt, arg...)                \
    do {                                                 \
        if (cond) {                                      \
            char *err_msg = NULL;                        \
            uci_get_errorstr(g_uci_ctx, &err_msg, NULL); \
            MY_ERR("%s : " fmt, err_msg, ##arg);         \
            free(err_msg);                               \
            goto bail;                                   \
        }                                                \
    } while (0)

If someone could tell me what I'm missing, I'd really appreciate it.

Simplifying it still further so that there is no usage of any "uci" library, MSVC falls at the first macro: error C2010: '.': unexpected in macro parameter list. Macros are not variadic functions. Why are you using macros?

You can start with a variadic function. If there are parts of it you think would be better as macros, work from there.

yes you are right and I am aware that uci is not related with the question itself. I just added it since I didn't wanted to write a stub for uci_get_errorstr. About using macros, it was the contention in that repository. Therefore, I didn't wanted to leave it.

@WeatherVane thanks a lot for the answers :) I will try to convert it, but can you tell me why the second one works whereas first one does not? I cannot see the difference that makes one of them works and other one not.

This ...
        MY_PRINT("Error  : " fmt, ##arg)

... from your MY_ERR macro expands to invalid C code when fmt is or expands to an identifier, such as err_msg.  You seem to be trying to perform a string concatenation, but that works only for string literals, and err_msg is not a string literal.
The solution you came up with, or something similar, is the simplest fix, though if you are determined to use variadic macros then you should probably use the standard form for them, with __VA_ARGS__ rather than GCC-style named variable arguments.

Hi @john-bollinger ,
Thanks a lot. It is strange that this has such simple reason. Thanks a lot for your answer :) Just one more question, can you suggest a better way to overcome this, or better way to achieve the same functionality?

@AzizKavas, it depends on what you consider "better".  One thing you could do would be to change PACKAGE_STR to a macro that expands to a string literal.  Then you could use string concatenation on that: "Not able to load package " PACKAGE_STR.  You should then still be able to use it in most any other way you already do, too.
